# What does this expression mean?

Tags: arithmetic

This is my first time writing, I hope this is the right forum for this. What does this mean?

"fraction numerator 48 over denominator square root of 16 to the power of begin display style 3 over 2 end style end exponent end root end fraction minus 3 to the power of 1 half end exponent times square root of fraction numerator 4 plus square root of 4 over denominator 2 end fraction end root"

Comment: It's just a string of unnecessarily complex algebra, like the math equivalent of a tongue twister.  We have notation for these sorts of things just to avoid these sort of run on sentences.

Comment: Yeah I know that. My question is how this can be interpetet as an expression like one plus one is 1+1

Comment: Just write it out term by term.  It's tedious but not difficult.  Note that $\sqrt 4 = 2, \sqrt {16}=4$ simplify the calculation.  Take a shot, anyway.  People here will help you through the details.

Comment: Ok. "48 over denominator square root of 16" thats 48/(16^(1/2)) but i dont get where " to the power of begin display style 3 over 2 end" is suppose to be.

Comment: Where did you get this expression from?

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit hard to understand but this is what I think:

"fraction numerator 48 over denominator square root of 16 to the power of begin display style 3 over 2 end style end exponent end root end fraction"
$\left(\frac{48}{\sqrt{16}}\right)^{3/2}= \left(\frac{48}{4}\right)^{3/2}= 12^{3/2}= (2\sqrt{3})^3= 24\sqrt{3}$

"minus 3 to the power of 1 half end exponent times square root of fraction numerator 4 plus square root of 4 over denominator 2 end fraction end root"
Here I have a problem- the standard interpretation of this is that the exponent applies to the "3" but you might intend it to apply to the entire thing.  Using the standard interpretation this will be $24\sqrt{3}- \sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{\frac{4}{2}}= 23\sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{2}$

Comment: "minus 3 to the power of 1 half end exponent **times** square root of ..." you have a plus there.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bad amalgamation of nested math formatting pseudocode with the escape characters removed. That, and the nesting is a bit loosy-goosy and ill-defined.

But, let's try anyway.

(By the way, real math isn't formatted like this. This is a mess. Did you pull this from a text version of a web page or something?)

I'll try to reformat the statement to highlight the structure.

`fraction
    numerator 48
    over
    denominator
       square root of
       16
          to the power of
             3 over 2
          end exponent
       end root
    (end denominator)
end fraction`

`minus`

`3 to the power of
    (start exponent)
    1 half
    end exponent`

`times`

`square root of
   fraction
      numerator
         4 plus square root of 4
      (end numerator)
      over
      denominator
         2
      (end denominator)
   end fraction
end root`

Taking this as the structure, the expression I put together looks like this:

$$\frac{48}{\sqrt{16^{3/2}}} - 3^{1/2}\times\sqrt{\frac{4+\sqrt{4}}{2}}$$

Comment: (sorry for bad english)I think this is the right interpertetion. And i got this from a webpage that didnt load properly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the way I parse it:

$$\frac {48}{\sqrt {16^{3/2}}}- 3^{1/2}\times \sqrt {\frac {4+\sqrt 4}2}=6-3=3$$